# R: html_nodes duplicating content on site

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am having a strange problem with html_nodes duplicating the content on a website.

Here's the basic code:

```
# I bring in a sample URL with a lot of CSS and Javascript
address <- "https://www.speedtest.net/"
content <- read_html(URLencode(address))
content %>%
    # I want to analyze the words on the page, so I bring in the body.
    html_nodes("body") %>%
    # I don't want Javascript and CSS cluttering the analysis, so I remove them
    html_nodes(":not(script)") %>%
    html_nodes(":not(style)") %>%
    html_text
```

html_nodes(":not(script)") effectively removes the Javascript clutter. *However*, it also -- for some reason -- duplicates every single line of text on the site so that my final output reads like this:

> Network Status Network Status Privacy Policy Privacy Policy Terms of
> Use Terms of Use             Do Not Sell My Personal Information Do
> Not Sell My Personal Information

I feel like this is just a syntax error on my part. Anyone know how to fix it? Or is there just a smarter way to achieve the same result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider this way:

```
address <- "https://www.speedtest.net/"
content <- read_html(URLencode(address))
content_data <- 
  content %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//body/descendant-or-self::*[not(name()='script' or name()='style')]/text()") %>%
  html_text(trim = T) %>%
  .[. != ""]
```